# How to set ask_variables_on_launch=True in AWX

Tags: ansible-awx

I'm following the response in this post to add extra_var in an AWX's API call. They say that ask_variables_on_launch must be set to True, but where can I change this in AWX exactly?

I tried adding ask_variables_on_launch: True in the variable section of the job template but this doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do this. The parameter ask_variables_on_launch can be changed by making an API call with PATCH.

Like this:

`curl -X PATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json" --user <USER>:<PASSWORD> -k https://<AWX_URL>/api/v2/job_templates/<JOB_ID>/ -d '{"ask_variables_on_launch": "true"}' | jq`